# How correctly to pass data from Singleton

Tags: c#, oop

I have Singleton class that get's data from web. And i need to pass those data to classes `FirstDerived` and `SecondDerived`. In this case is my class Singleton anti-pattern? Is it normal to use Aggregation relationship between DataSocket and `FirstDerived`, `SecondDerived`. Maybe it exist better object oriented solution?

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new TestViewModel();
    }
}

public class TestViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Base> Items { get; set; }
    public TestViewModel()
    {
        DataSocket.Instance.SendDataAsync();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Base>();
        Items.Add(new FirstDerived(1, DataSocket.Instance));
        Items.Add(new SecondDerived(2, DataSocket.Instance));
    }
}
public abstract class Base
{

}

public class FirstDerived : Base, IDisposable
{
    public FirstDerived(int id, DataSocket socket)
    {
        socket.Client += ProcessDataFromSocket;
    }

    public void ProcessDataFromSocket(string arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First Derived getting data: {0}", arg.ToString());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class SecondDerived : Base, IDisposable
{
    public SecondDerived(int id, DataSocket socket)
    {
        DataSocket.Instance.Client += ProcessDataFromSocket;
    }
    public void ProcessDataFromSocket(string arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second Derived getting data: {0}", arg.ToString());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public sealed class DataSocket
{
    private static DataSocket instance;

    public delegate void Messages(string info);

    public event Messages Client;
    private DataSocket() 
    {

    }

    public void SendDataAsync()
    {
        Action Send = new Action(SendData);
        IAsyncResult result = Send.BeginInvoke(null,null);
    }

    public void SendData()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if (Client != null)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Client("Test");
            }
        }
    }
    public static DataSocket Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance==null)
            {
                instance = new DataSocket();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: A cleaner approach would probably be to make DataSocket not a singleton/globally accessible.
But your question is to vague, and your "intent" is not known. Maybe this is the best approach, who knows?

To me, it looks a tad over-engineered and going down a dangerous route, maybe it does, maybe it doesn't.

Why do two classes always need to receive ALL data from socket? (Error handling, individual requests that only they want, caching responsibility)
If you know that there are two classes, why do you have them derive from an asbstract empty class and store them in a collection.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like `DataSocket` is the class that deals with networking, so any code to interact with the network should go there. Don't pass it into a constructor.

Rather, do something more like this sequence;

```
    DataSocket.Instance.SendDataAsync();
    Items = new ObservableCollection<Base>();

    var data1 = await DataSocket.ReadData();
    var data2 = await DataSocket.ReadData();

    Items.Add(new FirstDerived(1, data1));
    Items.Add(new SecondDerived(2, data2));
```

This way, your classes don't take a dependency on a global, constantly-changing object.

You might also want to consider some kind of `lock` statement to make sure that different parts of the code -- say, many different simultaneous web requests -- can't interfere with each other.